# Country from Geolocation API

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, gatsby

I'm working on a GatsbyJS e-commerce project and would like to have visitor country detection.
There are solutions based on Web API Geolocation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) which gives latitude and longitude from `navigator.geolocation`.

Other libraries (like, for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/geoip-lite) provide country code data based on IP input.

Is there any  solution (library, hook...) that combines these two and will return a country (or ISO country code) based on `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` coordinates?

Comment: You want to search for something that will help you with `reverse geocoding` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding

Comment: @mikeb Thanks for the hint! Will look up and get back with results

Answer (score 1):

There is a free api that can return a country code based on a lat long coordinate.

See the following:

> CountryCode / reverse geocoding 
>   The iso country code of any given point. 
>   Webservice Type : REST 
>   Url : api.geonames.org/countryCode?
>   Parameters : lat,lng, type, lang, radius (buffer in km for closest
>   country in coastal areas, a positive buffer expands the positiv area
>   whereas a negative buffer reduces it); 
>   Result : returns the iso country code for the given latitude/longitude With the parameter type=xml this service returns an xml document with iso country code
>   and country name. The optional parameter lang can be used to specify
>   the language the country name should be in. JSON output is produced
>   with type=JSON Example
>   http://api.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=47.03&lng=10.2&username=demo

Source: https://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html